# JSONP AJAX Call Error in IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-domain, jsonp

I am making a jsonp call as below .Its a cross domain call Which works fine in FF but in IE9 it fails and I see following message in IE .

```
SEC7112: Script from http://site.com/a.jsp was blocked due to mime type mismatch
```

I saw this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx where it says it will ignore response with No-Sniff response. So that header depends on server ? How do I fix it ? Is there any workaround ?

```
$.ajax({ type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.othersite.com/index.jsp',
        data: 'action=delete&id=121',
        contentType: 'application/javascript',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success:  function(data) {
                      alert(data.fromname);
        }
```

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory: The question is tagged with `cross-domain`, but the url is `index.jsp`. So, it's weird why the OP wants to do `JSONP`. _Edit_: The question has been edited, so `JSONP` is for cross-domain requests as the OP explained.

Comment: Check the response content type... it must match the ones in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx If the content type is another one and it contains the nosniff directive in the headers and if you don't have control over "othersite.com", you are out of luck

Comment: What is the response from the server? What is the response's MIME type? What is the error message?

Comment: You say "I see the following message in IE", but then there is no "following message".  An error message would be very useful.  If IE displays an error message, please share it.

Comment: @gilly3 I added the error text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error in MSDN says:

> SCRIPT and STYLESHEET elements will reject responses with incorrect MIME types if the server sends the response header X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff. This is a security feature that helps prevent attacks based on MIME-type confusion.

try sending the "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" in the server side of your page, if this does not works with ie, you just need to touch the www.othersite.com server headers.

ie sometimes is a headache.